# How can I move a CCNode along an arc, with linear animation speed?

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, bezier

I'm trying to animate a CCNode in a semi circle motion and have it constantly move at the same speed.  I thought I could achieve this with Bezier animation.

I'm trying to find the correct implementation to run an action with `CCActionBezierBy` ([ref](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCActionBezierBy.html)) that will not have an ease rate at all.

```
CGFloat duration = 5;
// bezierConfig is already set
CGFloat rate = 0.0f;
id action = [CCActionBezierBy actionWithDuration:duration bezier:bezierConfig];
id ease = [CCActionEaseRate actionWithAction:action rate:rate];
id spawn = [CCActionSpawn actions:action, ease, nil];
```

As I manipulate the rate I can see results, with 0 being the lowest ease animation.  But how can I make the animation completely linear?

Comment: by leaving out the ease action?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D by default CCactionBezierBy seems to have some sort of easing, so I'm trying to turn it off.

Comment: Bezier curves aren't linear, their very definition means that any stable moving-along-the-curve is inherently faster along strong curvatures and slower along gentle curvature. It also can't be "made linear" without requiring (for cubic curves) an order 6 easing function, which you won't have  available. If you just want a linear animation, just use a line, not a non-linearly controlled parametric curve.

Comment: ah, you mean the slowdown in curves? I'm afraid that's how it works, at least in this particular implementation. It's actually non-trivial to make spline movement where the object following the spline has a constant (or even user-influenced) speed.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added a sentence at the beginning of the post, I am trying to animate a CCNode in a semi circle motion at a constant speed.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thank you, I will look into spline movement

Comment: Might simply be easier to write your own path class then: moving an object about (x,y) at radius `r` over `phi` degrees (in radians; so for a half circle that's `pi`) is literally just updating its coordinate to `(x+cos(i)*r, y+sin(i)*r` where i starts at your current angle (found with the atan2 function) and ends at that-angle-plus-phi. Except for a straight line, probably the easiest path to quickly implement from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Place moving node in parent node. Its coordinates from parent root will be moving radius. Then make 2 rotation actions. One rotation of parent with constant speed. And rotation of node itself to the opposite direction.